# Como usar a biblioteca AFNetworking 2.0 de forma síncrona?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-service, rest

Gostaria de chamar um serviço rest usando a biblioteca `AFNetworking`.

Como fazer uma chamada de forma síncrona, ou seja, esperar o retorno do webservice?

Por exemplo:

Método que retornará um objeto carro:

```objective-c
Carro *carro = [self findCarroById:idCarro];
//restante do código... preciso ter a variável carro carregada antes de prosseguir.
```

Método que será chamado:

```objective-c
- (Carro *)findCarroById:(NSString *)idCarro {

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", @"http://www.site.com/rest/carro/", idCarro];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager GET:url parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id json) {
            Carro *carro = [[Carro alloc] init];

            carro.idCarro = [json objectForKey:@"id"];
            carro.descricao = [json objectForKey:@"descricao"];

            //talvez poderia colocar o return aqui
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Erro: \n\n%@", error);
         }
     ];

    return carro;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta não é a forma correta de proceder. Como você está lidando com uma chamada de HTTP, você não pode presumir que o aplicativo vá aguardar o término dela.

Implementações desta forma bloqueariam a interface de usuário se usadas na thread principal (o aplicativo aparentaria travado para o usuário), por isso a biblioteca AFNetworking nem mesmo se preocupa em realizar requisições síncronas.

Imaginando que você está carregando a informação de um carro para ser exibida em uma tela num app de iPhone, o que você deve fazer é solicitar a informação do carro no `- (void) viewDidLoad;`, e apresentar ao usuário um indicador de carregamento "Loading..." por exemplo.

Quando o carregamento for finalizado, ou seja, no block de success, você deverá então alterar as views com os dados novos carregados. Segue um exemplo:

```objectivec
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    // Solicita o carregamento do carro, porém não espera um retorno.
    [self loadCarWithId:carId];
    // Exibe indicador de progresso para o usuário.
    [ProgressHUD show:@"Loading..."];
}

- (void) loadCarWithId:(NSInteger)carId {
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", @"http://www.site.com/rest/carro/", carId];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager GET:url parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id json) {
            // Lida com os dados após o carregamento.
            Carro *carro = [[Carro alloc] init];
            carro.idCarro = [json objectForKey:@"id"];
            carro.descricao = [json objectForKey:@"descricao"];


            // Atualiza a tela com os dados do carro
            self.carIdLabel.text = carr.idCarro; // Assumindo que existe uma label "carIdLabel" na sua view.
            self.carDescriptionLabel.text = carro.descricao;  // Assumindo que existe uma label "carDescriptionLabel" na sua view.

            // Você também pode chamar um médoto quando esta requisição for concluída.
            [self saveCar:carro];
            // Remove o indicador de progresso pois o carregamento já foi concluído.
            [ProgressHUD dismiss];
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Erro: \n\n%@", error);
            // Remove o indicador de progresso pois o carregamento falhou.
            [ProgressHUD dismiss];
            // Avisa o usuário que o carregamento falhou ou tenta denovo.
         }
     ];

    // Não há retorno pois essa requisição é assíncrona.

}

// Isso só vai ser executado depois que a requisição for concluída
// já que está sendo chamado dentro do block de success.
- (void) saveCar:(Carro)carro {
    [[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] setObject:carro forKey:@"savedCar"]; 
    //Isso é apenas um exemplo, não funciona pois o objeto Carro precisa ser desserializado para ser salvo no user defaults.
}
```

EDIT:

Adicionado exemplo de indicador de atividade por meio do ProgressHUD: https://github.com/relatedcode/ProgressHUD

Comment: Obrigado @Julio, no meu caso vou apenas utilizar o `ProgressHUD`. Muito boa a sua explicação.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, acho que sua pergunta já foi respondida.. mas para completar e ajudar futuras duvidas... o pessoal da Ray Wenderlich posto essa semana um tutorial sobre o AFNetworking 2.0... segue o link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Comment: Já tinha olhado esse tutorial, mas parece que eles andaram atualizando. Valeu pela dica!

Comment: Cara não sei se já resolveu seu problema, mas segue um outro tutoria sobre o assunto que pode ajudar:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-nsurlsession-afnetworking-20--mobile-22651